# Correct syntax for variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to convert some ascii characters into another one. However I've been unable due to inexperience with variadic template syntax.

```
template<typename T>
void despecialize(const T& original, T& totransform, const int& charnum)
{
    if (static_cast<int>(totransform) == charnum) {
        totransform = original;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void despecialize(const T& original, T& totransform, const int& charnum, const int& charother...)
{
    despecialize(original, totransform, charnum);
    despecialize(original, totransform, charother...); //C3546 there are no parameter packs available to expand
}


std::string removePortugueseSpecialLetter(std::string& data)
{
    std::string transformed;
    for (auto& c : data)
    {
        despecialize('a', c, 176, 131, 132, 133, 134);
        transformed += c;
    }
    return transformed;
}
```

What should be the correct syntax?

Comment: **Once fixed**, you might get rid of recursion with(C++17): `(despecialize(original, totransform, charother), ...);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a variadic template, you need a variadic template parameter.  That looks like

```
template <typename... VariadicTypeParater>
// or
template <some_type... VariadicNonTypeParater>
```

Applying that to your function would give you

```
template<typename T, typename... Chars>
void despecialize(const T& original,
                  T& totransform,
                  const int& charnum,
                  const Chars&... charother)
{
    despecialize(original, totransform, charnum);
    despecialize(original, totransform, charother...);
}
```

Although this will allow any type to be passed for `Chars` instead of just `int`.  To constraint that you need to add SFINAE using `enable_if_t` non-type template parameter like

```
template <typename T,
          typename... Chars,
          std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Chars, int> && ...), bool> = true>
void despecialize(const T& original,
                  T& totransform,
                  const int& charnum,
                  const Chars& charother...)
{
    despecialize(original, totransform, charnum);
    despecialize(original, totransform, charother...);
}
```